# C# Parse out 2 different parts of a file name

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, substring

I have a need to parse out 2 parts of a file name

Example of what I need is "PartOne" and "PartTwo"

So a given file will always start with what I want up until an Underscore character,  then other part will always end with .txt

```
PartOne_PartTwo.txt
```

Desired Result would be

```
string a = "PartOne"
string b = "PartTwo"
```

I was trying to understand some regex like this... :/ :(   not sure I like regex...

```
^"(.*?)"\s+(\d[\d.]*)$
```

Real example

```
waterview_111254059820170506.txt
```

So result for that (what I need parsed out ) would be

```
string a = "waterview"
string b = "111254059820170506"
```

Substring or regex?

Comment: you can also use [string.Split](https://www.dotnetperls.com/split)

Comment: strip the extension and split on `_`?

Comment: I unfortunately do not do C#, nowhere was mentioned the size and form of the input (is it a textfile with filenames? is it files on disk, recursively across a filesystem? etc), and my answer came before the accepted answer. Please stay civil to people trying to help.

Comment: 1.  well , not sure what to say.  a non-programmer  / manager  / kid  could say what you said...    2.  you do not have an answer,   that is a "comment"  I do not see any answer from you.      Sorry to be blunt and possibly rude...  I'm just being honest with you .

Comment: Well you are asking "Substring or regex?" and I was presenting a possible third alternative, in a comment (not as an answer). But you have an answer so no need to go on about this any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`System.IO.Path` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] parts = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath).Split('_');
string a = parts[0].Trim();
string b = parts[1].Trim();  // possible exception if there was no underscore, check parts.Length > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use String.Split (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string s = "xxx_ssss";
var tokens = s.Split('_');
```

notice the simple quotes ('') since it is a char separator, not string.
the value of tokens is an array

```
tokens[0] = "xxx"
tokens[1] = "ssss"
```

Answer (score 0):

**the best way for get file name without extension is**

you can get the file name without extension from this system object,

```
string inputFile = @"c:\folder\partone_parttwo.ext";
string filename= System.IO.File.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile);
```

this is a robust and fast algorithm, it can extract the filename from a full path or only from a simple filename

**split file name parts without regexps:**
then you can split the string

```
  char delimiter = '_';
  string[] filenameParts = filename.Split(delimiter);
```

**split file name parts with regexps:**

```
  string pattern = "_"; 
  string[] filenameParts = Regex.Split(filename, pattern);
```